# Linked List from scratch. Trouble with header and footer

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

So I just started coding a Double Linked List in Java. For some reason, the header is not pointing to the footer when I create the linked list (or at least I don't think it is).

When I create the linked list, I just want to create a header and a footer, with the header pointing to the footer, and the footer pointing to the header:

```
public class ListNode //inner class
{
    T data;
    ListNode prev;
    ListNode next;
    public ListNode(T data, ListNode prev, ListNode next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

ListNode header;
ListNode footer;

public LinkedList()
{
    header = new ListNode(null, null, footer);
    footer = new ListNode(null, header, null);
}
```

I ran a simple test, just to see if this worked (this is all in the LinkedList class still):

```
public void test()
{
    if(header.next == footer)
    {
        System.out.println("reached");
    }
    if(footer.prev == header)
    {
        System.out.println("reached2");
    }
} 

public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.test();
}
```

Output: reached2

So its saying that the footer's previous pointer is pointing to the header, but the header is not pointing to the footer. Am I missing something really stupid here?

Comment: test() is in my LinkedList class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is, when the object `header` is created, `footer` is not exist, so you just passed a null to the param `next`

```
header = new ListNode(null, null, footer);//At this moment, footer is not initialized, so it is null
footer = new ListNode(null, header, null);//Only here, footer is created!
```

So you can fix it by using a setter method

```
 header = new ListNode(null);
 footer = new ListNode(null);
 header.setNext(footer);
 footer.setPrev(header);
```